# What is the meaning of the third derivative printed on this T-shirt?

Tags: soft-question, differentiation, calculus, jerk

Don't be a $\frac{d^3x}{dt^3}$

[image]

What does it all mean?

Comment: So that's a shirt that specifically asks mathematicians and physicists to not be jerks? Because...?

Comment: Related: [What came fist, Rice Crispy or Snap, Crackle and Pop?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41243/what-came-first-rice-crispy-or-snap-crackle-and-pop)

Comment: This question is not that bad, it is about the physical meaning of the time derivate of the acceleration and therefore a legitimate physics question. So it need not to be closed or something as certain people claim ...

Comment: An oxymoronic T shirt? :-)

Comment: At first, I thought, "Don't be a jolt", what does that mean? Then, I remembered that in some countries, it is called "jerk".

Answer (score 55):

It means *don't be a jerk.* The third derivative of position (i.e. the change in acceleration) is called "[jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29)", though it's a little used quantity. It's called jerk because a changing acceleration is felt as a "jerk" in that direction.

Answer (score 32):

In physics, sometimes the third derivative of position with respect to time is called [jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29).

Answer (score 1):

Jerk is the third derivative, fourth derivative is jump.